# MongoDB - replSet initial sync exception (Looping)

Tags: mongodb

I have a existing MongoDB replica set with 180GB of data (including indexes).

I am adding a new member to a replica set, in a different data centre to the existing members, the max supported disk IO of the new member is 32MB/s which means a time of around 90 minutes for data to be pulled from the Primary.

I setup the new replica set as per usual, with providing the keyfile and replica set name, and doing add member on the Primary.

However, the new database pulls all the data, rebuilds the indexes, and then complains about a lost connection. Here is the extract from the logs just when it finishes building the last index:

```
mongod.log:22791 [rsSync] build index done.  scanned 67083700 total records. 5615.59 secs
mongod.log:22792 [rsSync] Socket say send() errno:110 Connection timed out *.*.*.*:27017
mongod.log:22793 [rsSync] replSet initial sync exception: 9001 socket exception [SEND_ERROR] server [*.*.*.*:27017]  8 attempts remaining
```

This initial sync exception goes on to delete all the data files, and begin syncing again!

This has happened 4 times so far, so it is not an intermittent connection issue.

Primary Version: 2.6.5

New Member Version: 2.6.9

Any points as to why this is occurring would be very helpful.

Comment: You have to increase the timeout for replicasets to finish the job

Comment: Hi @Raghuveer - what timeout are you referring to here? Bearing in mind the process ran for approx. 3 hours pulling files and building indexes, before dieing at the end? Both services are in high availability data centres.

Comment: As you are going to have more number of replicasets sync bwt primary and secondaries will cause more load on primary. If you are using a version before mongodb 2.6.0 then see the bug https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13352. I am not sure but i think its load on primary which is causing this issue.

Comment: Thanks, I'm was replicating from 2.6.5 to 2.6.9 but I have upgraded the primary to 2.6.9 also and will see if this helps matters.

Comment: No, I've found that the error is that when I am building my largest index (72 minutes), the server tries to to send() and errors with Connection timed out then resyncs. Really it should at least try and reconnect!!

Comment: Now we to narrow down the problem, 1. can you check if all the connections are exhausted. 2. Is your query taking lot of time.